# Can't understand why SQL table won't update on statement

Tags: sql-server, sql-update, ssms, formula

In a survey, a row with the question name `3a` should equal the sum of the responses from the questions with the names `1a` and `2a`. This is the code I have:

```
UPDATE acrl.ACRLData_Edited_Test
SET question_textvalue = 
    cast(
     (SELECT question_textvalue 
       FROM acrl.ACRLData_Edited_Test a2 
       WHERE a2.ipeds_id = a.ipeds_id
           and a2.question_name = a.question_name and a2.question_name LIKE '1a.%'
     ) as decimal(10,2))
    + cast(
     (SELECT question_textvalue 
        FROM acrl.ACRLData_Edited_Test a2 
        WHERE a2.ipeds_id = a.ipeds_id
            and a2.question_name = a.question_name and a2.question_name LIKE '2a.%'
     ) as decimal(10,2))
FROM acrl.ACRLData_Edited_Test a
WHERE a.question_name LIKE '3a.%'
```

But it doesn't seem to work at all. When I run it, the survey responses/rows with the question `3a"` still show `Null`, instead of the number.

For example, I have an entry with the `1a` response as `4.7`, the `2a` response as `3.9` and the `3a` response is `NULL`. It should be `8.6` in that scenario.

Comment: Posting images of technical information like code or sample results, instead of formatted text, is the fastest way I've seen here other than spam for a question to be downvoted and then closed or ignored. Please edit the question to fix this, using the my edit of the first code sample as a guide. Otherwise, you are much less likely to get a good answer to this question.

Comment: Check your installation of SQL Server whether it is case insensitive.  Most are but maybe this one is not, in which case `a.question_name LIKE '3a.%'` won't match 3A. Total professional...

Comment: @ChrisMaurer That's not it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see this in the nested query in the first `case` expression:

```
 a2.question_name = a.question_name and a2.question_name LIKE '1a.%'
```

and also this in the final `WHERE` clause:

```
a.question_name LIKE '3a.%'
```

Logically, the `a2.question_name = a.question_name` condition means our `question_name` values must satisfy **both** `WHERE` clauses: the `a.question_name` restriction from the main outer `WHERE` clause and the `a2.question_name` restriction in the inner nested `WHERE` clause. It can only match records where the value is both `LIKE '3a.%'` **and** `LIKE '1a.%'`.

Those things cannot both be true, and therefore all the `3a.%` records will become `NULL` even if they weren't before. The same issue applies to the second `case` expression as well.

Also, the `.` has specially meaning in a `LIKE` match and adds no value here. You may as well use `LIKE '3a%'`, `LIKE '1a%'`, etc, but `LIKE '3a[.] %'` is most exact.

Answer (score 0):

What result are you getting if you run the below select statement?

```
SELECT a.question_name,
    cast(
         (SELECT question_textvalue 
           FROM acrl.ACRLData_Edited_Test a2 
           WHERE a2.ipeds_id = a.ipeds_id
               and a2.question_name = a.question_name and a2.question_name LIKE '1a.%'
         ) as decimal(10,2)) as SubQuery1,
    cast(
         (SELECT question_textvalue 
            FROM acrl.ACRLData_Edited_Test a2 
            WHERE a2.ipeds_id = a.ipeds_id
                and a2.question_name = a.question_name and a2.question_name LIKE '2a.%'
         ) as decimal(10,2))  as SubQuery2
    FROM acrl.ACRLData_Edited_Test a
    WHERE a.question_name LIKE '3a.%'
```

Does any of the two subquery columns return NULL value? If so, try enclosing it with ISNULL( cast(...),0) + ISNULL( cast(...),0).